# Why can't I see the initialvalues from NGRX when subscribing to my selector observable?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a NGRX application and I can't see it working with the selector. It doesn't show the initialvalues I put in the reducer. It only shows value after I dispatch an Action. 
Why I can't see the initialValue from the observable?

Here is the code:

```js
exportLoading$ = this._store.pipe(select(selectImbalanceDetailsExportLoading));

ngOnInit(): void {
   exportLoading$.subscribe(x=> console.log(x));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to see how you init the state, might you share it?

Also people say the next possible reasons:

> the reducer of the missing property had no default case for the actions, so it was returning undefined And for the empty object, I think it is just store-devtools that hide property with undefined value.

Info is taken from here: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1086#issuecomment-391373866